# Performance : Left JOIN with IS NULL join condition in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, left-join, isnull

```
select *
from Dummy LEFT JOIN data_stream_2
    ON ((Dummy.id_2=data_stream_2.id_2) OR
       (Dummy.id_2 IS NULL and data_stream_2.id_2 IS NULL))
```

This query takes 26 seconds. The moment I remove the IS NULL check, i.e

```
select *
from Dummy LEFT JOIN data_stream_2
    ON ((Dummy.id_2=data_stream_2.id_2))
```

it takes only 1.3 seconds.
How can I make the query faster?
It us similar to this case [Slow query with left outer join and is null condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069704/slow-query-with-left-outer-join-and-is-null-condition) but the difference is in his case join was not really required since he was using only columns from Dummy and not from data_stream_2. I need columns from both.

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?  Can you distinguish between a `NULL` arising from no match in the join and an actual value of `NULL`?

Comment: Are you sure that you compare the performance correctly? For example, did you try to issue each query several times in different orders. Maybe you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Yeah I am sure. SQLite Manager shows time in seconds

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you can separate the two parts of the OR into two parts of a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT *
FROM Dummy
LEFT JOIN data_stream_2
    ON Dummy.id_2 = data_stream_2.id_2
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Dummy
JOIN data_stream_2
    ON Dummy.id_2 IS NULL AND data_stream_2.id_2 IS NULL;
```

However, SQLite's IS operator can use arbitrary expressions on either side, and supports index optimizations, so you can simply use it to compare the IDs:

```
SELECT *
FROM Dummy
LEFT JOIN data_stream_2
    ON Dummy.id_2 IS data_stream_2.id_2;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried the solution but it has not made the query faster.